# What does a component or archive "now" mean in the apt Python API?

Tags: apt, repository, source-packages

I have a python script running on Ubuntu. Script gets all installed apt packages with

```
apt_cache = apt.cache.Cache()
```

I want to get repository names of each installed package. While I expect to see **xenial/main**, **xenial/universe**, **xenial-updates/main** etc. some of the packages have **now/now** for repository name.

```
('linux-headers-generic', [<Origin component:'now' archive:'now' origin:'' label:'' site:'' isTrusted:False>])
```

Most other packages are like:

```
('zip', [<Origin component:'main' archive:'xenial' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'de.archive.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>, <Origin component:'now' archive:'now' origin:'' label:'' site:'' isTrusted:False>])
```

What is the meaining of now here?

Answer (score 0):

Poking around the source code, the values become `now` when the version is from [the dpkg `status` file](https://github.com/Debian/apt/blob/1d9e29c9e2a5591b42a99a721b901fc003ed9149/apt-pkg/deb/debindexfile.cc#L145), which does not include where the package originally came from. Thus, you will see a version with archive `now` for any package that is currently installed. You can also see this in the output of `apt-cache policy`:

```
$ apt-cache policy
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
...
```

For example:

```
$  apt-cache policy apt
apt:
  Installed: 1.2.25
  Candidate: 1.2.25
  Version table:
 *** 1.2.25 500
        500 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

And the installed version will have these origins in the API:

```
<Origin component:'main' archive:'xenial-updates' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'jp.archive.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>
<Origin component:'now' archive:'now' origin:'' label:'' site:'' isTrusted:False>
```

However, if you get a version with `now` as the only origin, that means `apt` could not locate it in any source. This could happen for:

- an installed version that is no longer in any source (time to update!)
- a package installed using a deb file, with no corresponding package in the repositories
- a package installed from a source that was subsequently disabled